# Can I DeserializeWithLengthPrefix a c# class into a Python class?

Tags: c#, python, protocol-buffers

I have a lot of data Serialized with ProtoBuf in c#.

A colleague would like read these files with Python.

Can this be achieved as Python classes not same as c#.

Here is the c# class:

```
   [ProtoContract]
    public class TickRecord
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime DT;
        [ProtoMember(2, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsRequired = true)]
        public double BidPrice;
        [ProtoMember(3, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsRequired = true)]
        public double AskPrice;
        [ProtoMember(4, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsRequired = true)]
        public int BidSize;
        [ProtoMember(5, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsRequired = true)]
        public int AskSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like `protobuf-net`; fortunately, the library includes a tool to spit out the .proto schema for what it thinks of your model:

```
var schema = Serializer.GetProto<TickRecord>();
```

which comes out as:

```
message TickRecord {
   required bcl.DateTime DT = 1;
   required double BidPrice = 2 [default = 0];
   required double AskPrice = 3 [default = 0];
   required sfixed32 BidSize = 4 [default = 0];
   required sfixed32 AskSize = 5 [default = 0];
}
```

where `bcl.DateTime` is a protobuf-net complex data type described in "bcl.proto".

Frankly, I suggest changing your date-time to a `long` using unix time - it'll make things a lot simpler here. That gives you:

```
message TickRecord {
   required sfixed64 DT = 1 [default = 0];
   required double BidPrice = 2 [default = 0];
   required double AskPrice = 3 [default = 0];
   required sfixed32 BidSize = 4 [default = 0];
   required sfixed32 AskSize = 5 [default = 0];
}
```

which you can give to your colleague, and they can run `protoc` or whatever other platform/library tool they need for protocol buffers in their environment, and they should be set. The serialization format is intentionally cross-platform, so the *data* should work fine.

---

Note: `*WithLengthPrefix` works by wrapping the data in an outer shell. I need to see the exact parameters you are using to advise on how to advise your colleague.

Note: changing the `DateTime` to `long` is a breaking change; if you can't do that your colleague will have to look at bcl.proto (just Google it) and translate it into python.